# Getting next tag - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<button class="button" type="button"><span>Edit</span></button>
```

I want to have a click event on .button that changes the value of the next span.

So I have this as a test:

```
    $('.button').click(function(){
    $(this).next('span').val();
})
```

This returns 'undefined' however.  How can I select the span?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to fix two things. First `next()` applies to sibling elements. your `span` is inside your `button`. So change that to children. Next to get the value inside a `span` element you'll need to use .html()

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $(this).children('span').html();
})
```

EDITED:
Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hVGuK/)

Answer (score 1):

you want .text()  or .html() depending if you want just the text, or the markup to go along with it.

edit:

wait a second,  your span is inside your button?? interesting...
you can just use `$(this).text();` to get at the text then.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $(this).children('span').html();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` only works on form elements as far as I know. Use `.text()` or `.html()` to change the text of the `<span>`

Answer (score 0):

In you example, the span is not 'next', it is a child node. You would use next if your html looked something like this:

```
<button class="button" type="button">Click me</button><span>Edit</span>
```

Also, you want to get the text using html(), (as Björn mentioned)